# Different Ways to use simple_form in Ruby on Rails | What is the difference?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

What is the difference between these methods of addressing an edit form for "packs"?

How do these different approaches affect the stability of the application? It's versatility?

Where would these run into major problems? Why is one better than the other?

1. Via "method?" `<%= simple_form_for Pack.find(params[:id]), method: :patch do |f| %>`
2. Via Object `<%= simple_form_for @pack, url: pack_path(@pack), method: :patch do |f| %>`
3. Via Symbol `<%= simple_form_for :pack, url: pack_path(@pack), method: :patch do |f| %>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### 1. and 2. - Binding a form helper to a model instance

Are basically identical besides the fact that in 2. you're referencing a model instance from an instance variable instead of just passing the return value of a method call.

The end result is that you get a form that is bound to a model instance. This means that the value attributes of the inputs will contain the values from the model.

In fact all of these will give the same result:

```
<% 
  @pack = Pack.find(params[:id]) 
  pack = Pack.find(params[:id]) 

%>

<%= simple_form_for Pack.find(params[:id]), method: :patch do |f| %>
<%= simple_form_for @pack |f| %>
<%= simple_form_for pack |f| %>
```

But the first is less desirable since you should avoid doing queries directly from the view. The view should recieve data from the controler and use it to create HTML and be as simple and declarative as possible. Another major problem is that `.find` will raise `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFoundError` which should have been caught much earlier in the controller if the id is invalid.

### 3. Calling the form helpers with a symbol:

```
<%= simple_form_for :pack, url: pack_path(@pack), method: :patch do |f| %>
```

This creates a form that is "scoped" without necissarily being bound to an specific model instance. Take this example:

```
<%= simple_form_for :thing do  |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
<% end %>
```

This generates the following HTML:

```
<form novalidate="novalidate" class="simple_form thing" action="/things/new" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
  <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="F4r1gLuboZc1CKIdn9qac0sefxSVIvkjxk9KsD+sRl1wnVtEIKzHvWY0mPuLPvHI1Kcv3TIWD883YXHKXA+yJQ==" />
  <div class="input string required thing_name">
    <label class="string required" for="thing_name"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Name</label>
    <input class="string required" type="text" name="thing[name]" id="thing_name" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Note `name="thing[name]"` which means it will give a params hash which is just like if we had a model instance:

```
{
   thing: {
     name: "foo"
   }
}
```

This is not as commonly used (at least not correctly) since most of the time you're manipulating model instances but it does have a use in special cases like search forms.

Note that Rails will try to resolve the local variable `@thing` but will not raise an error if it is nil. Using this form is therefore generally not advised as it can mask errors.

The best way to understand this behavior is to read the docs for [ActionView::FormHelpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) which SimpleForm is just sugar on top of.

Comment: Also not that specifying `url: pack_path(@pack), method: :patch` are not necessary when you follow convention over configuration. Rails figures if the HTTP method is POST or PATCH by calling `.new_record?`. And makes a guess based on the model name that there is a `pack_path` or `packs_path` path helper.¨

Comment: "Note that Rails will try to resolve the local variable @thing but will not raise an error if it is nil. Using this form is therefore generally not advised as it can mask errors." I encountered this recently, is there a way to disable the instance variable resolving? I ended up dumping the *form_for* helper in favor of the *form_tag* for a search usage, because on some pages it was pre-filling itself or raising an error because I provided a symbol to a field that isn't a real attribute.

Comment: @max So, essentially removing the `(@pack)` would still leave the form functioning, but since it is guesswork would it be vulnerable to any kind of freak errors that including the object would avoid?

Comment: @JohanWentholt  I'm not aware of any configuration option to turn off the variable resolving that happen with `form_for` but the Rails 5.1 `form_with` helper that is meant to replace both `form_tag` and `form_for` solves this pretty much by requiring that you use the `model:` option which removes any potential ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

All three approaches yield the same form (assuming you're setting `@pack` to be `Pack.find(params[:id])`, however there are trade-offs:

1. It's not advisable to have an ActiveRecord call in your view code. Views should just be responsible for laying out the form, not for querying the database. Maintaining this separation will make long-term maintenance much more straightforward. Using a variable also means you can have the same form for both the `new` and `edit` screens, by setting `@pack = Pack.new` in your controller for the `new` view. For these reasons, I'd advise against option [1].
2. Using the object (`@pack`) or the symbol (`:pack`) yields the same results because internally the Rails `form_for` helper uses the symbol to look up the variable. IMHO option [2] and referencing the object directly is "better" because there's less magic going on, so it's easier for people new to the project (or you in a year's time) to understand. Option [2] is also consistent with the [Rails docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.0/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for) and SimpleForm docs, so it's less of a surprise for people to see.

Comment: I've also run into the problem where calling the symbol `:pack` will not be able to load in ruby error messages via `<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>` Is this just because of `.object`? or would calling `symbol: f.symbol` fix this issue?

Comment: The biggest problem with using a symbol is actually that it will mask nil errors. So instead of getting a nil error you get a bunch of translation errors or something else since the form is not bound to model which is less obvious.

Answer (score 0):

1 and 2 are indentical if you do `@pack = Pack.find(params[:id])` in your controller (and it is generally recommended).

3 is something you don't do as `simple_form_for` expects an object as first argument not a symbol (you might confuse it with something like `form.input :name`). I recommend you read the gem's README.

Comment: `simple_form_for` does accept a symbol as the first argument. It'll yield the same results as 1 and 2

Comment: oh, you're right though then the second argument is expected to be a `record_object` and the whole thing is passed to a `fields_for` and not to a `form_for` as the name `simple_form_for` would suggest. 
https://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/simple_form/master/SimpleForm/ActionViewExtensions/FormHelper#simple_form_for-instance_method

Personally I wouldn't use it as it is not describe in the README and you have to read the APIs code to figure the difference.